Quarkus - problem accessing HttpServletRequest
I'm developing a Java application, using Quarkus 2.13.8.Final.
There is a simple endpoint, in which I'd use the HttpServletRequest instance:
    @RequestScoped
    @Path("/rest/user")
    @Slf4j
    public class UserRestAdapter {
        @GET
        @Path("/canAccess")
        public Boolean canAccess(@Context HttpServletRequest request){
            log.info("canAccess, creating user context");
            if(request == null){
                log.info("canAccess, request is null");
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

However, calling that endpoint causes that exception:
javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: HTTP 400 Bad Request
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.ParameterHandler.handle(ParameterHandler.java:66)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:111)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:142)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:576)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
        at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
        at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: No bean found for required type [interface javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext] and qualifiers [[]]
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InstanceImpl.bean(InstanceImpl.java:190)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InstanceImpl.getInternal(InstanceImpl.java:211)
        at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InstanceImpl.get(InstanceImpl.java:97)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.core.parameters.ContextParamExtractor.extractParameter(ContextParamExtractor.java:100)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.ParameterHandler.handle(ParameterHandler.java:45)

How could I solve that issue?

The problem was caused by the usage of libraries quarkus-resteasy-reactive and quarkus-rest-client-reactive. After replacing these libraries with non-reactive versions, the endpoint correctly responded, as I wish.

By default, Quarkus REST runs on top of Vert.x, see RESTEasy Classic - Servlet compatibility. That's not built on top of servlets. You can probably replace everything that's related with servlets with Jakarta RESTful replacements, like jakarta.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders or jakarta.ws.rs.core.UriInfo.
If you really need to use servlets you need to include a dependency:
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-undertow</artifactId>
</dependency>

See HTTP Reference - https://quarkus.io/guides/http-reference#servlet-config for more information.

Using Jakarta or Undertow, how can I access to HTTP session?

There is no Jakarta RESTful replacement for the HTTP session so you'll need to include the quarkus-undertow dependency. Once you do that you should be able to inject the HttpServletRequest like you tried before, and use it access the HttpSession.

I included quarkus-undertow library in pom.xml, but I still notice the same error.

Can you try turning the @Context HttpServletRequest request parameter to an instance field?

I tried adding request as @Inject HttpServletRequest request, but the following exception has thrown: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT000048: No request is currently active

I didn't say @Inject but @Context. For Jakarta RESTful / JAX-RS there's a big difference between the two.

I also tried with @Context annotation, but the same exception has thrown: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT000048: No request is currently active
